# Leaflet-Search plugin error

Tags: leaflet

I try to connect [Leaflet search plugin](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search) to my map with GeoJSON data. But when I enter a search query in browser inspector I get error: `layer.getBounds is not a function in leaflet-search.js`. You can see it on http://ignn.ru/test/ (try to input "Volgograd" or "Alaska")

```
var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
        layer: ggg,
        propertyName: 'name',
        marker: false,
        moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
            //map.fitBounds( latlng.layer.getBounds() );
            var zoom = map.getBoundsZoom(latlng.layer.getBounds());
            map.setView(latlng, zoom); // access the zoom
        }
    });
map.addControl( searchControl );
```

I did this on example http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/geojson-layer.html

ggg: layer with geojson data

I understand because of this error the reason that do not give you any search results.

GeoJSON data - http://ignn.ru/test/test.js

Update:
In data there is a single object of type `point`. When I remove it, everything works. But I need the elements of type point.

Comment: currently moved in new website: https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/geojson-layer.html

Answer (score 2):

Here I load the search control, define the layer to search, the field to 
search, and then just use setView to zoom to the point. 
I set the zoom to 12 for grins. Since it's a point, I just set the zoom for all my points the same.

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/baseball/Baseball2.html

```
    var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
    layer: bbTeam,
    propertyName: 'Name',
    marker: false,
    moveToLocation: function(latlng) {
        map.setView(latlng, 12); // set the zoom
    }
});
```

Comment: Bill Chappell, Hm..Thank you! Tell me please. I have name in json for example (Volgograd City, Lenin street 10). and if i input Volgograd (first word) i have result. But when i input City or Lenin i not get result( Why?

Comment: I looked at your geojson data and you have points and multipolygons in the same file under the var statesData,  yet your var ggg is only using points 'circlemarkers', so don't have a polygon layer in your example to symbolize. As for the search only returning just by name, in your GeoJSON file I found "name":"Volgograd" which matched just the first name, so it is matching your data. You mention an address but your not using a geocoder, so you won't get street addresses.

Comment: Hello again =) Bill just look at http://ignn.ru/map, geojson at http://ignn.ru/map/hs.js.  Fox example - name = г. Волгоград п. 19 Партсъезда пер. Банный д. 6.  By  first word "г.Волгоград" i get result.  But.for example by next someone word like "Партсъезда" search pulgin don't found result =(

Comment: I looked at your GeoJSON and the first name was "  РѕР±Р». Р’РѕР»РіРѕРіСЂР°РґСЃРєР°СЏ, Рі. Р’РѕР»РіРѕРіСЂР°Рґ, Рї. 19 РџР°СЂС‚СЃСЉРµР·РґР°, РїРµСЂ. Р‘Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№, Рґ. 6" I couldn't find any names that matched your name, I'm guessing it's language/translate error. It may also be a data problem, I checked your data on https://jsonlint.com/ and http://geojsonlint.com/ both showed errors. In my example my JSON is:http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/baseball/BaseBallFinal.json and I use JQuery's $.getJSON to bring in the data, Try this. In my example type "B" and it should suggest.

Comment: http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/baseball/Baseball2.html  In this example have marker with name "White sox". When i type W or White i get result. But when i type sox i don`t get result..

Comment: It looks like that search plugin only uses a wildcard on the end of the string. Red So  will return Red Sox, Sox returns nothing. I used JQuery's autocomplete here. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Search/SearchState.html and if you type in York it will find New York. I used the names as ID's to search on, as they were unique, then populated the control with a list of the names. Only issue is the search names have to be unique. As for the plugin, you would have to ask the guy that wrote it.

Comment: @BillChappell do you know how to return the user input text from the search bar? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385055/leaflet-search-control-plugin-return-text-search-without-removing-autocomplete