# Leaflet Search Control Plugin return text search without removing autocomplete

Tags: leaflet

I am using https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search to search through some geojson. It works well but I am trying to return the text the user enters into the search to build a dynamic query. How do I capture the text without disabling the autocomplete?

```
states_layer= new L.geoJson(states).addTo(map);
var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
    position:'topright',        
    layer: states_layer,
    propertyName: 'name',
    initial: false,
    zoom: 11,
    marker: false,
}); 
map.addControl(controlSearch);
```

Code works good -- I was looking through the source code and tried to implement the `filterData` option.

```
filterData: function(text,records){
        console.log(text);
        console.log(records);
        }
```

This printed out the entered text and records but it took away the important autocomplete functionality from the layer search.

**Update**

[image]

**Update 2 using filter data return records**

```
filterData: function(text, records) {
  console.log(text);
  console.log(records);
  return(records);
}
```

breaks the autocomplete

[image]

**Update 3**

added

```
    filterData: function(text, records) {
      records = this._defaultFilterData(text, records);
      console.log(Object.keys(records));        
      console.log(records);
      return(records);
    }
```

[image]

which helps but this is not what I am looking for. I need when the user selects 1 record or types in the name fully and presses enter or the search icon -- I need that text or 1 record chosen.

I am trying to avoid writing a custom autocomplete search bar, anything in the source code worth tinkering?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828450/html-catch-event-when-user-is-typing-into-a-text-input  However it might only give you a bunch of word fragments before the autocomplete kicks in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea and logic is perfectly OK, you just forgot that filtering function must return whatever it filters. Since you actually do no filtering yourself, default filter function has to be called:

```
filterData: function(text, records) {
  console.log(text);
  console.log(records);
  records = this._defaultFilterData(text, records);
  return(records);
}
```

To catch the final searched text, you can use `moveToLocation` option function:

```
moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
  console.log(title);
  this._defaultMoveToLocation(latlng, title, map);
}
```

If you don't want to do the actual move, just leave default action out.

Comment: added your suggestion but it breaks the autocomplete see update pic. If I change it to return text the autocomplete suggests numbers instead of the layer data

Comment: You are right, I was careless when testing proposed solution. See modified answer.

Comment: The autocomplete works with your fix but it still just returns the records, really need the user entered text, or the 1 selected record after the user presses enter or the search button

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: great that worked! you're a life saver thank you